# pass parameters to stored procedure from parameter panel

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to pass parameters to a stored procedure in sqlserver from the controls I have added on a form in visual studio and not the default prompt which automatically appears when we run the application.
I want to pass three values as parameters.

`deliverystatus`-pending,approved,assigned,confirmed (anyone)

`startdate` and `enddate`

the data that is generated in the report is filtered on the delivery status and the date range.

But I cannot get the parameters to pass into stored proc from the control in my form.

Comment: `But i cannot get the parameters to pass into stored proc from the control in my form.`  Why not?

Comment: @udit Where is your code? It's better to locate your code so others can answer you with more detail...

Comment: how can i?when i run the application...it comes up with a default window..that asks for the parameters but i want to bypass that default prompt and directly pass the parameters from the form itself which i have attached with the crystal report viewer

Comment: @mj-y i dont have any code for this..i have just added a crystal report viewer on a form and three radio buttons and two date pickers as well on the same form.i just want that when i select one radio button and date in date pickers it should be passed to the stored procedure parameters...but cant figure out how to do that

Comment: not again man...y u all c# geeks cant help a beginner but just mark the question as -1.

Comment: @udit  I agree COMPLETELY!  Too many Question Nazis on SO.  BUT, if you plan to keep using SO, its best to learn better formatting and how to include enough info to make your question easier to answer.

Comment: @udit You didn't even mention anywhere in your post that you were doing anything with Crystal Reports. y u beginner cant ask a proper question?

Comment: you mean you did not write the Stored procedure code? how do u connect to database from your C# application? (I mean with ado.net or linq or ...)

Answer (score 1):

It's  a sample code to create a procedure in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MJTestProc]
    @deliverystatus NVARCHAR(50),
    @startdate DATETIME,
    @enddate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl1 
    WHERE deliverystatus = @deliverystatus
      AND DeliverDate >= @startdate
      AND DeliverDate <= @enddate
END
```

and below is a sample code for connecting to database and read data via a procedure:

```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public void GetDataFromStoredProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection SConnect = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand SCommand = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter SAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SConnect.Open();

        // in the next line you execute your stored procedure with form controls content
        SCommand.CommandText = "exec [dbo].[MJTestProc] '" + RadioButton1.Text + "' , '" + DatePicker1.Text + "' , '" + DatePicker2.Text + "'";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SAdaptor.Fill(dt);
        SConnect.Close();

        //here you can assign dt content to a control. Below code is a sample to assign data to the reportviewer
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource myreportDataSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();

        try
        {
            myreportDataSource.Name = "DataSource name in rdlc file";
            myreportDataSource.Value = dt;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(myreportDataSource);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourNamespace.YourRDLCfilename.rdlc";

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

You can assign this function to your radiobutons "CheckedChanged" event and datepickers "ValueChanged" event, so it runs every time that radiobuttons or datepickers value changed.

(I wish it helps you)